# CakePHP - paginate and sort hasMany association

Tags: sorting, cakephp, paginator

I have three tables:

Book -> **belongTo** -> Document ,Document -> **hasOne** -> Book, Document -> **hasMany** -> Language , Language -> **belongTo** -> Document

**Document.php**

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Book' => array(
        'className' => 'Book',
        'foreignKey' => 'document_id',
        'dependent'=>true,
    )

public $hasMany = array(
    'Language' => array(
        'className' => 'Language',
        'foreignKey' => 'document_id'
    )
```

**Book.php**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Document' => array(
        'className' => 'Document',
        'foreignKey' => 'document_id'
    )
);
```

**Language.php**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Document' => array(
        'className' => 'Document',
        'foreignKey' => 'document_id'
    )
);
```

**BooksController.php**

```
    $this->Book->bindModel(array(
        'hasOne' => array(
            'Language' => array(
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array('Document.id = Language.document_id')
    ));

    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->Paginator->settings = [
        'conditions' => $this->Book->parseCriteria($this->Prg->parsedParams()),
        'contain' => array('Document','Language')
    ];
    $this->set('books', $this->Paginator->paginate());
```

**index.php**

```
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Document.Language.type',__('language')); ?></th>
```

I just can't sort data by language type!

Can anyone suggest a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the virtual field feature in order to sort by language type.

First, add this virtual field to your Document model:

```
public $virtualFields = ['Min_LangType' => 'SELECT MIN(type) FROM languages as Language WHERE Language.document_id = Document.id'];
```

Then, sort by language type in this way:

```
$this->Paginator->sort('Document.Min_LangType',__('language'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! your virtual field is Min_LangType therefore you should say Document.Min_LangType in index.php. I can't believe the answer was so simple!